# Complex ordering in django db query

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have the following entries in my database:

```
`title`            `status`
Titanic            WIP
Avatar             WIP
Terminator         Complete
Abyss              Default
```

I want to sort these objects by the status of the object: Default, then WIP, then Complete. The correct ordering would then be:

```
Abyss / Default
Avatar / WIP
Titanic / WIP
Terminator / Complete
```

How would I do the following db call?

```
Title.objects.order_by(status='Default', status='WIP', status='Complete',title)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329849/django-order-by-specific-order

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django order\_by specific order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329849/django-order-by-specific-order)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this query, you can use django's `extra`:

```
titles = Title.objects.all()
ordered_query = titles.extra(select={
                'ordering':"(
                    case when status='Default' then 1 
                         when status='WIP' then 2
                         when status='Complete' then 3
                    end)"
                }).order_by('ordering', 'title')
```

Comment: In Django **1.8** you don't have to use `extra` you can use [Conditional Expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/) see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31611225/953553