# Ordering a queryset by occurrences

Tags: mysql, django

I have a django model:

```
class Field:

choice = models.CharField(choices=choices)

value = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

In my database I have some cases where there are 3 "fields" with the same choice, and some cases where there is 1 field of that choice

How can I order the queryset so it returns, sorted by choice, but with all ones in a set of 3 at the start?

For example

`[1,1,1,3,3,3,4,4,4,2,5]` where `1,2,3,4,5` are possible choices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best I can do using django's ORM. Basically, just like in SQL, you have to construct a custom order_by statement. In our case, we'll [place it in the SELECT and then order by it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10330601/3096768):

1) Get a list of choices sorted by frequency: `[1, 3, 4, 2, 5]`

```
freq_list = (
    Field.objects.values_list('choice', flat=True)
    .annotate(c=Count('id')).order_by('-c', 'choice')
)
```

2) Add indexes with enumerate: `[(0,1), (1,3), (2,4), (3,2), (4,5)]`

```
enum_list = list(enumerate(freq_list))
```

3) Create a list of cases: `['CASE', 'WHEN choice=1 THEN 0', ..., 'END']`

```
case_list = ['CASE']
case_list += ["WHEN choice={1} THEN {0}".format(*tup) for tup in enum_list]
case_list += ['END']
```

4) Combine the case list into one string: `'CASE WHEN choice=1 THEN 0 ...'`

```
case_statement = ' '.join(case_list)
```

5) Finally, use the case statement to select an extra field 'o' which will be corresponding order, then just order by this field

```
Field.objects.extra(select={'o': case_statement}).order_by('o')
```

---

**To simplify all this**, you can put the above code into a `Model Manager`:

```
class FieldManager(models.Manager):
    def get_query_set(self):
        freq_list = (
            Field.objects.values_list('choice', flat=True)
            .annotate(c=Count('id')).order_by('-c', 'choice')
        )
        enum_list = list(enumerate(freq_list))
        case_list = ['CASE']
        case_list += ["WHEN choice={1} THEN {0}".format(*tup) for tup in enum_list]
        case_list += ['END']
        case_statement = ' '.join(case_list)
        ordered = Field.objects.extra(select={'o': case_statement}).order_by('o')
        return ordered

class Field(models.Model):
    ...
    freq_sorted = FieldManager()
```

Now you can query:

```
Field.freq_sorted.all()
```

Which will get you a `Field` `QuerySet` sorted by frequency of `choices`

Comment: It seems when I implement this, Field.objects is no longer there, so `Field.objects.values_list('choice', flat=True)` doesn't work. Possibly as this model manager is overriding the default one - is there a way to get both?

Comment: @entangly Yeah, you just need to explicitly include the default manager by adding `objects = models.Manager()` to the `Field` class.

Answer (score 0):

You should make a function and detect which is repeated to select unique, then calling from mysql as a function over mysql