# Django queryset place of None/Null in orderby in Postgresql

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have a queryset that I am ordering by -DateTimeField

model:

```
class QuestSubmission(models.Model):
    quest = models.ForeignKey(Quest)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
    ...
    time_returned = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

queryset:

```
QuestSubmission.objects.all().order_by('-time_returned')
```

In my sqlite3 tests, this order newest to oldest followed by None/Null entries

But on my Postgresql server the order is None/Null then newest to oldest.

How can I get my postgresql order_by to place the None/Null values at the end similar to the sqlite3?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15121093/django-adding-nulls-last-to-query

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
select * from dude order by case when date is null then 1 else 0 end, date desc;
 test  |    date    
-------+------------
 test2 | 2001-01-04
 test2 | 2001-01-03
 test2 | 2001-01-02
 test2 | 2001-01-01
 test  | 
 test2 |
```

example:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When, Value, IntegerField

SomeModel.objects.annotate(
    nulls_last=Case(
        When(time_returned__isnull=True, then=Value(1)),
        When(time_returned__isnull=False, then=Value(0)),
        output_field=IntegerField(),
    )
).order_by('nulls_last', '-time_returned')
```

from here: [Django order_by specific order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10329849/django-order-by-specific-order)