# Use Set of Choices as the order_by

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

```py
class OrganizationAccount(AbstractUser):
    OrgRole = [('President', 'President'),('Internal VP', 'Internal Vice President'), ('External VP', 'External Vice President'),
    ('Treasurer', 'Treasurer'), ('Secretary', 'Secretary'), 
    ("Assistant Secretary", "Assistant Secretary"), ("Auditor", "Auditor"), ("Outreach Program Director", "Outreach Program Director"), ("Event Coordinator", "Event Coordinator"),
    ("Public Information Officer", "Public Information Officer"), ("Digital Officer", "Digital Officer"), ("Representative", "Representative"), ('Member', 'Member')
    
    
    ]
    role = models.CharField(choices = OrgRole, max_length=32)
```

I'm looking for a way to call

```py
OrganizationAccount.objects.all().order_by('OrgRole')
```

In a sense that it would produce a query set in this order (Pres, Internal VP, External VP, ...)

Is there any way to execute this?

Comment: You can create your custom logic. This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31611225/12306993

Answer (score 0):

#### ===== try this (models.py) =======

```
class OrganizationAccount(models.Model):
    OrgRole = [('President', 'President'),('Internal VP', 'Internal Vice President'), ('External VP', 'External Vice President'),
    ('Treasurer', 'Treasurer'), ('Secretary', 'Secretary'), 
    ("Assistant Secretary", "Assistant Secretary"), ("Auditor", "Auditor"), ("Outreach Program Director", "Outreach Program Director"), ("Event Coordinator", "Event Coordinator"),
    ("Public Information Officer", "Public Information Officer"), ("Digital Officer", "Digital Officer"), ("Representative", "Representative"), ('Member', 'Member')
    
    
    ]
    OrgRole.sort()
    role = models.CharField(choices = OrgRole, max_length=32,)
```

#### ==== Output ======

[image]